# how to set unique id for every element in html using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have lots of classes in my html but i want every class(or id if i have to change) be unique.here this code should work. i have lots of `class="answer-to-q"` in my code and when i click on specific one, that `<div>` should slide down not others.

```
 <div style="text-align: right;margin: 20px 20px 0 0">
      <p class="answer-to-q">please log in
      <span uk-icon="icon:  plus-circle"></span>
       </p>
  </div>
```

jquery:

```
 $(".answer-to-q").click(function () {
       $(".post-a-answer-div").slideDown("slow");
  });
```

Comment: Where is the element with `.post-a-answer-div`?

Comment: it's in the same page. i have lots of this `.post-a-answer-div` actually

Comment: when i click on one of the `class="answer-to-q"` all of `.post-a-answer-div` slide down and i dont want it

Comment: Which `.post-a-answer-div` you want to slide down?

Comment: look i have lot's of `class="answer-to-q` and also lots of `.post-a-answer-div`. i want them to be unique. means that specific  `class="answer-to-q` can slide down specific `.post-a-answer-div` not all of them. i know i have to use `id` selector but they should be unique to work. :|||

Comment: Use [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) in `jQuery`. It allows you to add custom attributes to your DOM elements and access them directly by using a key you have provided.

Comment: @alex how can i use it? i couldn't find a solution.

Comment: @Technotures it's a very broad question. Using a setter: `$('#myElem').data('id', 'my-custom-id-1');`. This will add `data-id=my-custom-id-1` to your element, then you can access it using ``$('#myElem').data('id');`

Answer (score 0):

Ideally I think you should to set the IDs when you're generating the HTML, but if that's not possible, something like this could work? I'm using data attributes instead of IDs because that seems more appropriate but it could be modified to work with IDs if you really need to use 'em.

```
// Add data attributes
var count = 1;
$('.answer-to-q').each(function(){
  $(this).attr('data-q', count);
  $('body').find('.post-a-answer-div:not([data-a])').first().attr('data-a', count);
  count++;
});

// Toggle on click
$('.answer-to-q').click(function(){
  var target = $(this).attr('data-q');
  $('[data-a="'+target+'"]').toggle();
});
```

Example:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xzaBgM